# On li element hover, apply color to anchor tag in SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following CSS I need to convert to SASS:

```
#menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fafafa;
}
```

How would this be translated?

edit: looking at it, i will try:

```
    menu{
       li{
          &:hover{
                  a{
                     color: #fafafa;
                   }
          } 
       }
   }
```

Comment: Try your code first.  If it doesn't work, then ask your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#menu
  li
    &:hover
      > a
        color: #fafafa
```

Or

```
#menu{
       li{
          &:hover{
                  > a{
                     color: #fafafa;
                   }
          } 
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have only used .less but tried in http://sassmeister.com/ and SASS result is:

```
#menu li:hover > a 
color: #fafafa
```

Comment: pretty much the same then?

Comment: Looks like it is correct, I checked an article http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/convert-css-to-sass/